# Docker networking: Why can I have 2 containers which have opened the same port

Tags: docker, networking

I understand port mapping with `-p`. I understand I can only map my container port on one port on the host network:

```
$ docker run -d -p 8080:80 nginx
```

There can no other container map its port on 8080 because there is already running a container.  This port 8080 will be mapped on docker0 port 80 and so on on docker-container-port 80.

But I don't really understand why I can have another nginx:

```
$ docker -run -d -p 8888:80
```

I have to map my port on a different port of the host (8888) but why can my docker0 network open port 80 2 times? there are 2 containers behind it with port 80. I know it works but I just don't understand why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each container runs in a separate network namespace.  This is an isolated network environment that does not shared network resources (addresses, interfaces, routes, etc) with the host.  When you start a service in a container, it is as if you have started it on another machine.

Just as you can have two different machines on your network with webservers running on port 80, you can have two different containers on your host with webservers running on port 80.

Because they are in different network namespaces, there is no conflict.

For more reading on network namespaces:

- https://blog.scottlowe.org/2013/09/04/introducing-linux-network-namespaces/
- https://lwn.net/Articles/580893/